# The Value of One Function Determines the Value of Another

Tags: functions, terminology, special-functions

The value of $\pi(s)$ determines the value of $m(n)$. How do we describe such a relationship between two functions in standard terminology? How do we express this mathematically?

Comment: Do you mean $m(n, \pi(s))$? If not, how does $pi(s)$ determine the value of $m(n)$?

Answer (score 1):

The particular relation you're thinking of is probably functional composition; that is, if the value of $\pi$ determines the value of $m$, there the should be some function $f$ such that
$$f(\pi(n))=m(n)$$
which just takes the given value for $\pi$ and uses it to find the appropriate value for $m$. We would write this relation as
$$f\circ \pi = m.$$